# Выдаёт ошибку "Имя не существует в данном контексте"

Tags: c#, unity3d

Речь идет о cubeToCreate, по идее он  должен ссылаться на if Input.GetMouseButtonDown .
Код писал по инструкции, у человека у которого списывал все норм у меня ошибку выдает.
Вот собственно весь код, может что то упустил.

```
using UnityEngine;

using System;

using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    private CubePos nowCube = new CubePos(0, 1, 0);
    public float cubeChangePlaceSpeed = 0.5f;
    public Transform cubeToPlase;

    public GameObject gameToCreate, allCubes;

    private List<Vector3> allCubesPositions = new List<Vector3> {
        new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        new Vector3(1, 0, 0),
        new Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
        new Vector3(0, 1, 0),
        new Vector3(0, 0, 1),
        new Vector3(0, 0, -1),
        new Vector3(1, 0, 1),
        new Vector3(-1, 0, -1),
        new Vector3(-1, 0, 1),
        new Vector3(1, 0, -1),
    };
    

    private void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(ShowCubePlace());
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.touchCount > 0) {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
            if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase != TouchPhase.Began)
                return;
#endif

            
            GameObject newCube =  Instantiate(
                        cubeToCreate, <<<----- ВОТ ОН ГАД ТАКОЙ
                        cubeToPlase.position,
                        Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

            newCube.transform.SetParent(allCubes.transform);
            nowCube.setVector(cubeToPlase.position);
            allCubesPositions.Add(nowCube.getVector());

            SpawnPositions();
        }
    }

    

    IEnumerator ShowCubePlace() {
        while (true) {
            SpawnPositions();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(cubeChangePlaceSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void SpawnPositions() {
        List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x + 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z))
            && nowCube.x + 1 != cubeToPlase.position.x)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x + 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z));
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x - 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z))
           && nowCube.x - 1 != cubeToPlase.position.x)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x - 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z));
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y + 1, nowCube.z))
           && nowCube.y + 1 != cubeToPlase.position.y)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y + 1, nowCube.z));
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y - 1, nowCube.z))
           && nowCube.y - 1 != cubeToPlase.position.y)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y - 1, nowCube.z));
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.z + 1))
           && nowCube.z + 1 != cubeToPlase.position.z)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.z + 1));
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.z - 1))
           && nowCube.z - 1 != cubeToPlase.position.z)
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.z - 1));

        cubeToPlase.position = positions[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, positions.Count)];
    }

    private bool IsPositionEmpty(Vector3 targetPos) {
        if (targetPos.y == 0)
            return false;

        foreach (Vector3 pos in allCubesPositions) {
            if (pos.x == targetPos.x && pos.y == targetPos.y && pos.z == targetPos.z)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
    struct CubePos {
        public int x, y, z;

        public CubePos(int x, int y, int z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }

        public Vector3 getVector() {
            return new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }

        public void setVector(Vector3 pos) {
            x = Convert.ToInt32(pos.x);
            y = Convert.ToInt32(pos.y);
            z = Convert.ToInt32(pos.z);
        }
    }
```

Comment: И где у вас этот `cubeToCreate`? Вот нажмите `Ctrl+F` и напишите там `cubeToCreate`, увидите этот объект? Я не вижу, вижу допустим `public Transform cubeToPlase;`, ок, а `cubeToCreate`? Где хоть одна ссылка на него?

Comment: [1](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/). Ставлю 2 рубля, что вы ни один из учебников не видели. **Unity** - движок, **C#** - топливо, а **вы** - механик. Как бы круто вы не разбиралсь в движке, без горючки вы никуда не уедете.

Comment: Да учебники я не читал. Подскажите толковые, очень уж большой массив выбора не хочу тратить время на бестолковые пособия. Я имею в виду нужны материалы по которым можно учится пособия для профи меня пока не интересуют.                                                                                       
 А по поводу  cubeToCreate  он там есть, ща выделю!

Comment: То что я вам скинул, это для новичков. А по поводу `cubeToCreate`, у вас его нет. Мне вам рассказать про классы, объекты, переменные, поля и свойства, или вы сами почитаете? Если у вас нет времени искать информацию, запишитесь на платные курсы. Знания из воздуха не берутся, они берутся из опыта, а чтобы получать опыт, надо инвестировать время, но у вас его нет. Следовательно, вы в тупике. Не буду больше вас задерживать.

Comment: Спасибо я ссылки сразу не заметил. Я на этом сайте новичок, ща почитаю.

Comment: Но я всё равно не понимаю как вы не видите cubeToCreate я понимаю что не включил его куда нужно но он ведь написан .Я имею в виду в коде что я выложил . Я нажал Ctrl+F вписал и он его сразу показал что на этой странице что в среде разработки так что в этом плане   я вас не пойму.

Comment: Чтобы использовать переменную, ее надо где-то объявить. Например если напишите `Console.WriteLine(myText)`, этот код у вас не скомпилируется с той же ошибкой, потому что компилятор не знает, где взять переменную `myText`. Вот и у вас то же самое, вы пытаетесь использовать то, чего нет. Вот пример объявления `public Transform cubeToPlase;`, другими словами `cubeToPlase` у вас есть, а `cubeToCreate` - нет.

Comment: Я знаю и умная среда разработки мне тоже это предложила и кучу других вариантов  причем самому писать не надо она сама дописывает. НОО во первых когда я это делаю это ломает ту часть кода в которую он вписан а во вторых как я уже писал выше этот код сделан под копирку и я в недоумении почему у меня он выдает ошибку а в оригинале её нет. Буду теперь сам учить язык и писать заново тут по другому ни как. Спасибо что уделяете время мир не без добрых людей!!

Comment: Вот вам [быстрый старт](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ), я сам когда-то учился по ним.

Comment: Очень любопытно вы смотрите уроки и "делаете под копирку", вот прям [очень](https://youtu.be/IvSn89poszM?t=2059).

Comment: Черт возьми это он и есть, тот самый видос.Я на эти сорок минут весь день убил. Я повторял потому что я так лучше запоминаю и понимаю когда сам делаю нежели когда просто смотрю. У меня так забавный случай произошел мне нужно было проанализировать массив данных и я искал программу где это можно было бы сделать нашёл видос где в Rstudio учили анализировать данные ну я освоился с прогой сам вносил данные какие нужно и только потом догнал что работал с языком R. Вот так забавно бывает.

Comment: Ну собственно вот. Вы опечатались. В видосе всё видно, как должно быть.